# problem with match namespace in xslt

Tags: xslt, namespaces

It's a problem with match elements which have specific node.

The xml：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" herf="B1.xsl"?>
<profile xmlns:base = "urn:mytest:baseInfo"
xmlns:prf="http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/profiles/UAPROF/ccppschema-20021212#">
    <base:Description>
        <base:text>description of profile</base:text>
    </base:Description>
    <prf:Component>
        <prf:Keyboard>PhoneKeyPad</prf:Keyboard>
        <prf:Model>SampleModel</prf:Model>
        <prf:NumberOfSoftKeys>3</prf:NumberOfSoftKeys>
        <prf:PixelAspectRatio>1x1</prf:PixelAspectRatio>
        <prf:ScreenSize>128x240</prf:ScreenSize>
    </prf:Component>
</profile>
```

and the XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:base = "urn:mytest:baseInfo" xmlns:prf="http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/profiles/UAPROF/ccppschema-20021212#">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="prf:*">
    <xsl:variable name="temp">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$temp}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>description of profile<Component>
    <Keyboard>PhoneKeyPad</Keyboard>
    <Model>SampleModel</Model>
    <NumberOfSoftKeys>3</NumberOfSoftKeys>
    <PixelAspectRatio>1x1</PixelAspectRatio>
    <ScreenSize>128x240</ScreenSize>
</Component>
```

Why the "description of profile" is also output? It has "base" namespace.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: Because you never tell the XSLT processor to ignore it.

You provide a template that processes `prf:*`, but you do not forbid the processing of `base:`. Given nothing else, the XSLT processor applies *default behavior* ([built-in rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule), also [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/defaultrule.html#d3635e76)) to any nodes it encounters that are not handled by any custom template.

The default behavior for element nodes is:

- copy their text-node children to the output,
- process their child elements

Knowing that, your `<base:Description>` and `<base:Text>` elements produce exactly what you see. To prevent it, either catch them with an empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="base:*" />
```

or direct the program flow manually by defining a template for the root node:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="profile/prf:Component" />
</xsl:template>
```